# ruby on rails time_ago_in_words doesn't display seconds ago

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, locale, seconds, timeago

Here is my **en.yml locale**

```
en:
  datetime:
    distance_in_words:
      less_than_x_seconds:
        one: "1 sec"
        other: "%{count} secs"
      x_seconds:
        one: "1 sec"
        other: "%{count} secs"
      less_than_x_minutes:
        one: "1 min"
        other: "%{count} mins"
      x_minutes:
        one: "1 min"
        other: "%{count} mins"
      about_x_hours:
        one: "1 hour"
        other: "%{count} hours"
      x_days:
        one: "1 day"
        other: "%{count} days"
      about_x_months:
        one: "1 month"
        other: "%{count} months"
      x_months:
        one: "1 month"
        other: "%{count} months"
      about_x_years:
        one: "1 year"
        other: "%{count} years"
      over_x_years:
        one: "1 year"
        other: "%{count} years"
      almost_x_years:
        one: "1 year"
        other: "%{count} years"
```

Whenever i post something i use

```
<%= link_to time_ago_in_words(post.created_at), post_path(post) %>
```

to display the time ago since the post was created but instead of showing **1 sec**, **2 secs** etc... it displays **1 min**, and continues with **minutes**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass `true` to `time_ago_in_words`'s `include_seconds` parameter:

```
time_ago_in_words(post.created_at, true)
```

See the [documentation for `distance_of_time_in_words`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words), which is used by `time_ago_in_words` for more detail.

Comment: thanks, there is another problem now... it wont display 1 by 1 seconds... just 5 by five or even more like 10 by 10 seconds...

Comment: That's how the function works, it shows an approximate time not an exact one (see [`distance_of_time_in_words` code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bd8a9701c27b4261e9d8dd84aebbde6ba784ed83/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L80)). If you want exact times you need to write your own helper.